# SQL: Creating View From 2 Tables Without FK Relationship

Tags: sql-server, join

I am attempting to create a view by joining two tables together: **Bid** and **Item**. There is no FK relationship linking Bid and Item directly. Instead, Bids can have Sections which have Items.

So far I have something like this..

```
CREATE VIEW FWOTBAItems AS
    SELECT f.Id, i.Id, i.ISBN10
    FROM [tracs].dbo.FWOBid f
    JOIN [tracs].dbo.FWOItem i ON i.SectionId = [ any section corresponding to FWOBid f ] && i.ISBN10 = "TBA"
```

Here is a simple example of my tables:

---

**Bid**

*Id*

**Item**

*Id*

*ISBN10*

*SectionId*

**Section**

*Id*

*BidId*

---

I want to retrieve all Item's where Item.ISBN10 = "TBA", but also include the corresponding Id from **Bid** in the view.

**Id** (from Bid) | **Id** (from Item) | **ISBN10** (will always equal "TBA")

Comment: Can you create this as a sqlfiddle? It seems like it should be fairly straight forward but there just isn't much detail here to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to join to the section table as well. You don't need to select any columns from it though, just use it to get the relationship.